# drupal site in my apache2 localhost is not opening

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-7, http-status-code-404

I installed drupal7 in my system using command `sudo apt-get install drupal7`, it was installed in `/use/share` folder, my localhost was configured to `/var/www`. I was able open drupal site in `localhost/drupal7/` but i didnt had any drupal7 folder in `/var/www`. Now due to permissions issues i moved the drupal7 folder to `/var/www` now i am getting `404` error when i open `localhost/drupal7`. how to make this work properly....

Answer (score 0):

open this file
`sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/drupal7`
"sites-available" it means where your site is avalable for example "htdocs"

and change line DocumentRoot "old address" to this
`DocumentRoot /var/www/drupal7`

if it's not exist so make file drupal7 and past
`<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@drupal7
        ServerName drupal7
        DocumentRoot /var/www/drupal7
</VirtualHost>`
and run
`sudo a2ensite drupal7`
restart your apache with this command
 `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: There is no file called drupal7 in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`